# Copy all formulas in one column into the next X-1 number of column, X is user defined

Tags: excel, vba

There are complex formulas in Column B.
I want by the user entry in cell A1, to paste the formulas from Column B into Column C and so on.

For example:
If A1 is "1", Column B will be the only column with formulas.
If A1 is "2", Column B and C will have the same formulas (copying all of B into C).
If A1 is "3", Column B, C, D will have the same formulas (copying all of B into C and D).

If A1 is 4, Column B, C, D, E should populate with formulas.
If the user changes A1 from 4 to 2, only Column B and C with formulas should be populated - D and E should disappear.

I'm not able to figure out the conditional component of A1 in the paste special.

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy the Same Formulas

- Copy the code into the sheet module of the worksheet (e.g. `Sheet1`) where you want it applied (**NOT** in a standard module e.g. `Module1`).
- The code runs automatically i.e. there is nothing to run.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Start error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TARGET_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const FIRST_SOURCE_CELL As String = "B2" ' adjust!
    
    ' Check if the value in the target cell has changed.
    Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = Intersect(Me.Range(TARGET_CELL), Target)
    If tCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' target value has not changed
    
    ' Check if the target value is valid.
    
    Dim CellValue As Variant: CellValue = tCell.Value
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = Me.Range(FIRST_SOURCE_CELL)
    Dim sCol As Long: sCol = sfCell.Column
    
    Dim IsValid As Boolean

    If VarType(CellValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        If CellValue = Int(CellValue) Then ' is an integer (whole number)
            If CellValue >= sCol Then
                If CellValue <= Me.Columns.Count - sCol + 1 Then IsValid = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If Not IsValid Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the Source (single-column) range.
    
    If Me.FilterMode Then Me.ShowAllData
    
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With sfCell
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        rCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the formulas from the Source range to an array.
    
    Dim Data() As Variant

    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Formula
    Else
        Data = srg.Formula
    End If
    
    ' Resize the array to the necessary number of columns
    ' and copy the formulas from the first to the remaining columns.
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = CLng(CellValue) - 1
    
    If cCount > 1 Then
        
        ReDim Preserve Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
            
        Dim r As Long, c As Long
        
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 2 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = Data(r, 1)
            Next c
        Next r
    
    End If
    
    ' Write the formulas from the array to the Destination range.
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        sfCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(rCount, cCount).Formula = Data
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
' Continue error-handling routine.
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & ":" _
        & vbLf & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 Thank you very much for the reply. I should have specified in the original prompt, but I need this to detract a column if A1 goes down. So for example, if the user puts in 5 in A1 and then decides to put 1 in A1 after, I will need it so that the number of columns goes down from 5 to 1. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that the rest to the right of the last column should be empty?

Comment: Yes, so A1 would really dictate how many columns of formulas there should be. If A1 is 1, then Column B should be the only column with formulas there, and if A1 is 4, Column B, C, D, E should populate with formulas. But if the user changes A1 from 4 to 2, only Column B and C with formulas should be populated - D and E would disappear. I hope this makes sense.